# Solr Memory Usage increases by a lot during and after optimization

Tags: solr

I am facing a situation, when I do an optimization by clicking on the "Optimized" button on the Solr Admin Overview UI, the memory usage of the server increases gradually, until it reaches near the maximum memory available. There is 64GB of memory available in the server.

Even after the optimized is completed, the memory usage stays near the 100% range, and could not be reduced until I stop Solr. Why could this be happening?

Also, I don't think the optimization is completed, as the admin page says the index is not optimized again after I go back to the Overview page, even though I did not do any updates to the index.

I am using Solr 5.3.0, with 1 shard and 2 replica. My index size is 183GB.

Regards,
Edwin

Comment: Good amount of information is available here : [solr-commit-and-optimize-](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137607/solr-commit-and-optimize-questions)

Comment: Why do you think the optimize is completed? You say it isn't reflected as being completed on the admin console. Most likely the optimize is still running and is taking a long time because you are exhausting the memory on the system. An optimize operation can take double the disk space and memory depending on the circumstances.

Comment: The admin console shows a green tick besides the optimize. But when I click somewhere else and return to the Overview page, it shows that it is not optimized again. Before the optimize, the memory usage is around 7GB, but after the optimize, it shot up to the full 64GB available in the server.