# Not able to optimize solr index in solr 8.7

Tags: optimization, solr, lucene, solr8

I have 2 standalone deployments of solr with versions 8.7.0 and 7.5.0. On 7.5.0 I am able optimize the index the way specified here - [How to optimize solr index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954358/how-to-optimize-solr-index) but the same is not working for 8.7.0

Answer (score -1):

Whats is the error you are getting in 8.7.0?
Post the command used in both versions, it should work in both versions ideally.

For your info:

Running an optimize will remove all of the deleted documents from your index and will create a single segment. This operation will create segments much larger than the maximum considered for future merges and you’ll have to perform this operation routinely. This is a very heavy-weight operation that doubles the index size during its execution and basically rebuilds the index again.

So you need to be sure if you want to optimize your index or not.

Comment: More details on optimize command : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137607/solr-commit-and-optimize-questions/3737972#3737972